# How do I check if .wmv file is corrupted?

Tags: wmv, file-corruption, media-player-classic

Whenever I try to play .wmv in an media player, it won't start playing by itself. When I slide the bar a little further only then it does. Could be the .wmv file corrupted from the beginning? How can I check this to make sure if it is?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try and use [AsfBin](http://www.radioactivepages.com/asfbin.aspx?p=0) to try and fix the wmv file.
I use this regularly to fix my wmv files. Just save the entire file again through AsfBin with default settings. It usually fixes most of the wmv files.

Comment: The output format seems to be .asf, there's no option for .wmv. So, I guess the quality won't be the same.

Comment: There is no re-encoding of video so there will be no loss of quality. If you are really concerned about the extension, you might as well rename the output to .wmv without any issues.

Comment: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/284094