# WMV video file only plays partially

Tags: video, windows-media-player, wmv, media-player-classic

I have a WMV file which I converted from streaming from a camcorder via a firewire port.

This worked perfectly before and I could watch it from start to finish in the past, as well as seek to any location in any video player.

What I've noticed today is, when I play it, I can only watch the first 3 hours, it won't let me watch the last hour in Windows Media Player.

Even worse in Media Player Classic, it will only let me watch the WMV if I watch it from the start, so I can't seek to 2 hours into the video and watch from there.

Anyone know if this is a common issue on WMV's or my file has just become corrupted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find the answer here and used AsfBin to repair it

[How do I check if .wmv file is corrupted?](https://superuser.com/questions/471880/how-do-i-check-if-wmv-file-is-corrupted?rq=1)